# Is there a way to monitor the CPU / Memory of a Fargate Task that isn't part of a service

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

I am running a fargate task from a task definition, that task is not part of a service. It's essentially a "one shot" task I want to run to completion, so doesn't make sense to be part of a service

I'm trying to monitor the CPU & Memory usage of that task - however I can't find a way to do it. Cloudwatch metrics seem to only offer the values by service name (as part of "ECS > ClusterName, ServiceName).

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Good question. The metric dimensions are cluster or cluster/service. You might consider a cluster per type of ‘one shot’ task or have a service with a desiredcount of 0 that you toggle on and off to complete the work. When I get back to computer with AWS enabled I’d be curious to figure out the best option here.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. Creating a cluster per fargate task (since a fargate cluster is merely a placeholder) would work, but seems overly complex just to get metrics...